# Azure SQL database auditing for DML & DDL oprations

Tags: azure-sql-database

We have Azure SQL database with audit enabled for security purpose. The Client security team has asked us list of information from Azure databases.

1.View or create a report of all newly created/amended/deleted records
2.View or create a report containing the contents of all deleted records
3.View or create a report of all changes to a given record
4.View or create a report of all user access profiles
5.View or create a report of all user id login and logout times over a specific period
6.View or create a report of functional usage by user ID of system activity over a specific period, e.g. list the number of times each type of system activity (report, query, accession, etc.) was accessed on a certain day by a user
7.View or create a report by system activity on user access over a specific period, e.g. for each system activity (report, query, accession, etc.) list each user who accessed on a particular day
8.View or create a report of the queries performed by users”

Certainly, we get from audit logs who and what kind of operation done on database. but we won't get what are exact data changes like what rows inserted /which data updated & data before update and after/ what exactly user deleted.

Solution tried: We tried temporal tales for azure sql db change tracking. it gives us changed Data of DML operations, But doesn't not give if DDL operations are done like change column name /drop column/add column  etc.

SQL EXPERTS COULD YOU PLEASE HELP.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

[DDL Triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/ddl-triggers?view=sql-server-2017) can really help you to keep track schema changes on your Azure SQL Database. Below is an example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER safety   
ON DATABASE   
FOR DROP_TABLE, ALTER_TABLE   
AS   
   PRINT 'Save change on a log'   
   SELECT EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand/CommandText)[1]','nvarchar(max)');
```

Database Auditing can help with schema changes and dropped objects. Below an example:

```
Set-AzureRmSqlDatabaseAuditing `
 -State Enabled `
 -ResourceGroupName "resourcegroupname" `
 -ServerName "ssqlinstancename" `  #ssqlinstancename.database.windows.net
 -StorageAccountName "strageaccountname" `
 -DatabaseName "dbname" `
 -AuditActionGroup 'SCHEMA_OBJECT_CHANGE_GROUP' `
 -RetentionInDays 8 `
 -AuditAction "DELETE ON schema::dbo BY [public]"
```

For DML operations, you mentioned you found a solution with Temporal Tables but Database Auditing can help also:

```
Set-AzureRmSqlDatabaseAuditing -ResourceGroupName "resourceGroup"
 -ServerName "SQL Server Name" -DatabaseName "AdventureWorksLT"  
 -StorageAccountName "storageAccount" 
-AuditActionGroup "SUCCESSFUL_DATABASE_AUTHENTICATION_GROUP", "FAILED_DATABASE_AUTHENTICATION_GROUP", "BATCH_COMPLETED_GROUP" 
 -AuditAction "UPDATE ON database::[AdventureWorksLT] BY [public]"  
 -RetentionInDays 60
```

For auditing database logins and connections to the database, please read [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5180/azure-sql-database-auditing-using-blob-storage/) article.

Comment: Thanks Alberto... I will test these and reach out in case of any troubles.. Thanks Lot..